# How to set X and Y position dynamically that is enter by user in Drawtext FFMpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'll create Fade-In-Fade-Out Command to display Text on Video. But i have Display text when user display.below is my dynamic command which is used in Android :

```
-i /storage/sdcard0/Animation/Video_1561462248215.mp4 -vf drawtext=textfile=/storage/sdcard0/Notes/TextFile.txt:fontsize=40:fontfile=/data/data/com.videomaker.animation/files/Fonts/Comic_Neue.ttf:fontcolor=ff00ff:box=1:boxborderw=1:boxcolor=ffffff:shadowcolor=000000:shadowx=1:shadowy=1:alpha='if(lt(t,2),0,if(lt(t,3),(t-2)/1,if(lte(t,(6-1)),1,if(lt(t,6),(6-t)/1,0))))':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2 /storage/sdcard0/Text_Animation/Demo_1562234479205.mp4
```

In the above example, i have applied X and Y static like Display text in Center of the Video But i want to Display Text in Every Place when the user said.

Also, i want to know that How to work X and Y position calculate in FFMPEG (like w means that Width of Video, text_w means that text of Width.)But i can't understand that how we decided that values and how it works in the FFMPEg command?

Comment: What is your specific question? Please explain what exactly you need and where you are stuck. Also, we don't deal with Android programming here, so please keep your question relevant to FFmpeg command line usage only. Thanks.

Comment: i want to display Text on a particular  X-Y position .And this question is related to FFMPEG .

Comment: You just need to set `x` and `y` to different values, or am I misunderstanding you? I am assuming you already know how the command that you are using works. (I still see no actual question in your post or comment.)